# Why can't I access this array in Smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

Given this in the Smarty template:

```
<pre>{$user->settings['sendStats']|@print_r:1}</pre>
```

The output in the browser is this:

```
Array
(
    ['period'] => daily
    ['ofPeriod'] => year
    ['points'] => 1000
)
```

Doing any of these:

```
<pre>{$user->settings['sendStats']['period']|@print_r:1}</pre>
<pre>{$user->settings['sendStats'][ofPeriod]|@print_r:1}</pre>
<pre>{$user->settings['sendStats'].points|@print_r:1}</pre>
<pre>{$user->settings.{'sendStats'}.{'period'}|@print_r:1}</pre>
<pre>{$user->settings.{sendStats}.{period}|@print_r:1}</pre>
```

with or without the `|@print_r:1` gives no output in the browser.

I also tried assigning `$user->settings` to a Smarty variable and I get the exact same result (as expected).

---

How do I access the elements of the `$user->settings['sendStats']` array?

Answer (score 1):

`{$user->settings.sendStats.period|@print_r:1}` should work just fine. Also have a look at the [Variables](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.syntax.variables.tpl) page in the docs…

Answer (score 0):

The array values itself are not arrays (your array is not multidimensional), so you should drop the `|@print_r:1` and you should be fine. Should look something like:

```
<pre>{$user->settings['sendStats']['period']}</pre>
```

Comment: Did that, but nothing changed. Also, if the values are not array then the print_r would still output them as they are.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. The array keys contained single quotes, so the answer would have been:

```
{$user->settings['sendStats']["'period'"]}
```

I fixed it so the keys didn't contain quotes anymore.